# First Time Web Services in ASP.NET VB

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-services

I am attempting to call a web service using JS from an asp.net website (VB) client side. I have used web services before but never set one up. I want to run async updates and queries. Any help would be great, similar examples, or better practices. Cant post images...

I believe I am having issues with Namespaces and proper calling of the methods from client events. Maybe something with the webconfig?

**What I have done so far:**
Make a new asp website in visual studio (website1). Add a new .asmx file named WebService.asmx. 
Uncomment System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService(). Create a service reference using the wizard (ServiceReference1). On default.aspx add the script manager. Create button onclick and function. Then I run and I get this error on the js.

How I'm trying to call the service, I have done it like this in the past. One a system that was not mine. Does this method work?:

```
    function test() {
        ServiceReference1.WebService.HelloWorld();            
    }
<input type="button" onclick="test()"/>
```

What the WebService.asmx looks like, I have no NameSpace for that test. Should there be one?:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function

End Class
```

The app_reference successfully imports and the webservice runs alone fine. Also my webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WebServiceSoap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:55800/WebService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WebServiceSoap" contract="ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoap"
                name="WebServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

JS fires and breaks on webservice line with this message:

```
Unhandled exception at line 13, column 13 in http://localhost:55800/Default.aspx

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'ServiceReference1' is undefined
```

Any advice?

Comment: Did you try it like `WebService.HelloWorld()`?

Comment: You dog...haha worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the `{WebServiceClass.Method}`.

```
WebService.HelloWorld()
```